# Adding color to row to last value column using specified word in a cell with macro

Tags: excel, vba, colors, cell

I'm practically brand new to macro so my questions might seem completely illogical, but now i'm trying to have macro to automatically color specific rows (depending on specific words in a specific sentence in a cell). I also need the row to be colored to a specific column and not the entire row. I've tried a lot of different codes but nothing seems to happen and I don't get any errors either.. Please help me with some kind of code that I can use for my issue.
[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgqD4.jpg)
[VBA Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgPE5.jpg)
I want to color the highlighted cells in the row in Orange, this would be based on the two letters "UH" that are in the cell but disregard the rest of the words, so whenever Macro finds "UH" it would apply orange color to the selected cells, and also a different color for "E-Line" and other words which I could add later with the same coding. (Also the sheet name is Untitled).

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Your question is not supported by any screenshots/ data. What you are asking seems possible. But, it would be hard to imagine everything. Please see a few other questions and [code on how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then you will have better idea.. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I edited and posted an image to the sheet that i want macro on with a brief/clear description of what I needed, and really thank you for the quick comment. It's seriously greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your VBA code is still missing?

Comment: I deleted the code I had for the coloring because it wasn't working and thought I'd create a new one and add it between the coding I already have.. Again I just started using macro yesterday, so this is pretty basic and might be a bit confusing..

Comment: If there are not many columns, conditional formatting will be sufficient for the job. No macro needed.

Comment: The thing is I need the macro because this will copy right after the coloring to another workbook. I don't know if that makes any sense.